# can I get the code lines containing specified words with git api

Tags: gitlab-api

I want to get all code lines which contains specified words like `orderInfo` in `git.xxx.com`. And I read [gitlab api document](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/) and it seemed I can get only the projects which contains specified word.
This is my expected output:

```
xxx orderInfo[].....
yyy orderInfo.....
....
hhh orderInfo.....
```

Is there any simple way?

Comment: What did you try so far? Post your code as a [mcve]! What happened when you ran it? What did you expect to happen instead? What specifically are you having problems with?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the search scope "blobs". Note that this requires Elastic Search to be enabled. Otherwise, you can simply checkout with git and locally use `grep`.